# Sailfish OS App Development for Beginners

Tags: qt, sailfish-os

Just wanted to get a reference for Sailfish OS App development.Which are all the good books and forums for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

The current Sailfish Silica docs are at:
  https://sailfishos.org/develop/docs/silica/

There are no official forums yet but there is the #sailfishos channel on IRC (irc.freenode.net) - say "hi" when you join :)

SailfishOS App development is (as you realise) Qt based - you can use C++ or just QML. The Qt Project has excellent resources around these technologies.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid Sailfish OS project is at an early stage so far. It is based on [Mer](http://www.merproject.org/) and [Nemo](http://wiki.merproject.org/wiki/Nemo) so you can refer to the documentation of both projects.
The official mailing list is: devel-subscribe@lists.sailfishos.org. There's also a IRC channel (#sailfishos) at irc.freenode.net.

I'll include a few links that might help:

- [Current project documentation](https://sailfishos.org/sailfish-silica/index.html)
- [Programming for Sailfish OS with the Sailfish OS SDK - video tutorial for beginners](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=z3hMGNwObx8#!)
- [FlyingSheep on Sailfish](http://flyingsheeponsailfish.blogspot.ch/)